# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, crud-repository

Error Message I am getting

> Error creating bean with name 'libraryController' defined in file :
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0:
> Error creating bean with name 'libraryService' defined in file.
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2:
> Error creating bean with name 'lendRepository' defined in
> com.restapi.respository.LendRepository defined in
> @EnableDynamoDBRepositories declared on DynamoDBConfig: Could not
> create query for public abstract java.util.Optional
> com.restapi.respository.LendRepository.findByBookAndStatus(com.restapi.model.Book,com.restapi.model.LendStatus);
> Reason: No property 'book' found for type 'Lend' Did you mean
> ''bookId''

LendRepository.Java:

```
import org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.EnableScan;
import com.restapi.model.Book;
import com.restapi.model.Lend;
import com.restapi.model.LendStatus;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

@EnableScan
public interface LendRepository extends CrudRepository<Lend, String> {
    Optional<Lend> findByBookAndStatus(Book book, LendStatus status);
}
```

Book.java:
package com.restapi.model;

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "book")
public class Book {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String name;
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String isbn;
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String authorId;

}
```

LibraryService.java:

```
public List<String> lendABook (BookLendRequest request) throws Exception {
        Optional<Member> memberForId = memberRepository.findById(request.getMemberId());
        if (!memberForId.isPresent()) {
            throw new Exception("Exception message");
        }
        Member member = memberForId.get();
        if (member.getStatus() != MemberStatus.ACTIVE) {
            throw new RuntimeException("User is not active to proceed a lending.");
        }
        List<String> booksApprovedToBurrow = new ArrayList<>();
        request.getBookIds().forEach(bookId -> {
            Optional<Book> bookForId = bookRepository.findById(bookId);
            if (!bookForId.isPresent()) {
                try {
                    throw new Exception("Exception message");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            Optional<Lend> burrowedBook = lendRepository.findByBookAndStatus(bookForId.get(), LendStatus.BURROWED);
            if (!burrowedBook.isPresent()) {
                booksApprovedToBurrow.add(bookForId.get().getName());
                Lend lend = new Lend();
                lend.setMemberId(memberForId.get().getId());
                lend.setBookId(bookForId.get().getId());
                lend.setStatus(LendStatus.BURROWED);
                lend.setStartOn(Instant.now().toString());
                lend.setDueOn(Instant.now().plus(30, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toString());
                lendRepository.save(lend);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you please share your `Lend` object with us?

Answer (score 0):

The error message and solution suggestion is pretty obvious.

> Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional com.restapi.respository.LendRepository.findByBookAndStatus(com.restapi.model.Book,com.restapi.model.LendStatus); Reason: No property 'book' found for type 'Lend' Did you mean ''bookId''

Your `findByBookAndStatus()` method that you created in `LendRepository` appears incorrect. You don't have a `book` property for your `Lend` object. Perhaps you are keeping the `id` value of the `Book` as a property in your `Lend` object.

If you have an attribute named `bookId` in your `Lend` object, your method should be:

```
Optional<Lend> findByBookIdAndStatus(ID id, LendStatus status);
```

Your first argument in the method should be the same as the data type of the `id` attribute of your `Book` object.

Answer (score -2):

Annotate *'LibraryService'* class with **@Service**.

Comment: In the shared error message, it seems clear that the error is not caused by this.